# links in rest app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, hyperlink

Im working with ruby 1.9.2, rails 3.2.1, and mysql, I have a rest app, but the links dont works,when I go to the localhost:3000 I get:

> ```
> Errno::ENOENT in WsController#registro
>
> No such file or directory - C:/Ruby192/PROYECTOS/loteriab/doc/loteria_registro.wsdl
> Rails.root: C:/Ruby192/PROYECTOS/loteriab
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
> app/controllers/ws_controller.rb:43:in `get_result'
> app/controllers/ws_controller.rb:33:in `registro'
> ```

here is code:

**my view.html.erb**

> ```
> > <div id="menu">         <ul>            <li>            <%= link_to "login", root_path %><p
> > >es el proceso mediante el cual se controla el acceso individual al webservice de loteria mediante la identificación del usuario
> > utilizando credenciales provistas por el usuarioUn usuario</p>          <%=
> > link_to "registro", root_path %>
> >         
> >         
> > 
> >             <%= link_to " login ", "ws/registro"  %>
> >              </li>      </ul>   </div>
> ```

**my routes:**

```
root :to => 'ws#inicio'


  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
   match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

**my controller:**

```
require 'savon'

class WsController < ApplicationController   def inicio   end

  def login
    data = {"Version" => "xx",
      "CodEmpresa" => "xx",
      "Rut" => "1579xxxxx-x",
      "Clave" => "xxxx",
      "SO" => "xx",
      "Tipodispositivo" => "xx"}

    response = get_result("loteria_autentificacion", data)

    render :text => response


       end

  def registro
    data = {"Version" => "01",
      "CodEmpresa" => "01",
      "CodAgente" => "01",
      "Rut" => "1579xxxxx-x",
      "email" => "xxxx@xxxxxxx.com",
      "Clave" => "xxxx",
      "SO" => "xx",
      "Tipodispositivo" => "xx"}

    response = get_result("loteria_registro", data)

    render :xml => response   end

  def get_result(service, data)
    client = Savon::Client.new do
      wsdl.document = File.expand_path("#{Rails.root}/doc/#{service}.wsdl", __FILE__)
    end

    response = client.request :wsdl, service do
      soap.body = data
    end

    return response.to_xml   end end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line in your code, `wsdl.document = File.expand_path("#{Rails.root}/doc/#{service}.wsdl", __FILE__)` is telling savon to look for the WSDL at "C:/Ruby192/PROYECTOS/loteriab/doc/loteria_registro.wsdl".

The error is saying that the WSDL file, loteria_registro.wsdl, is not where the code line specifies. Either download the WSD and place it there or change the `wsdl.document` to point to the Web Service.

Comment: @suely Great! Go ahead and hit the check mark then if this resolved the issue